# Spring boot validation annotations @Valid not working

Tags: java, spring-boot

Given below is my main controller from which I am calling the **submitWatchlistItemForm** method.

```
package com.openclassrooms.watchlist;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView;


@Controller
public class WatchlistController {

    private List<WatchlistItem> watchlistItems = new  ArrayList<WatchlistItem>();
    private static int index = 1;
    
    @PostMapping("/watchlistItemForm")
    public ModelAndView submitWatchlistItemForm(@Valid WatchlistItem watchlistItem, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    
        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return new ModelAndView("watchlistItemForm");
        }
        
        WatchlistItem existingItem = findWatchlistItem(watchlistItem.getId());
```

Below is the **(command Object) WatchlistItem class** where I have defined some variables with validation annotations and corresponding getter/setter methods.

```
package com.openclassrooms.watchlist;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

public class WatchlistItem {
    
    private Integer id;

    @NotBlank(message="Please enter the title")
    private String title;
    private String rating;
    
    @Priority
    private String priority;
    
    @Size(max=50, message ="Comment should be maximum 50 characters")
    private String comment;
    
    
    public WatchlistItem(Integer id, String title, String rating, String priority, String comment) {
        super();
        this.title = title;
        this.rating = rating;
        this.priority = priority;
        this.comment = comment;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public WatchlistItem() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
```

Below is the my form binded to the command object WatchlistItem

```
<form action="#" method="post" th:action="@{/watchlistItemForm}" th:object="${watchlistItem}" >
            <h2 class = "mt-4">Submit an item</h2>
            <hr/>
            <!-- Form levels error messages here -->
            <div class = "form-group row ">
               <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <span class="text-danger" > </span>      
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class = "form-group row ">
               <label for = "title" class = "col-sm-2 col-form-label">Title</label>
               <div class = "col-sm-4">
                  <input th:field="*{title}" type = "text" class = "form-control" placeholder = "Mandatory">
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <span class="text-danger" th:errors="*{title}"> </span>            
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class = "form-group row ">
               <label for = "rating" class = "col-sm-2 col-form-label mr-0">Rating</label>
               <div class = "col-sm-4">
                  <input th:field="*{rating}" type = "text" class = "form-control" placeholder = "5.0 < Number < 10.0">
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <span class="text-danger"> </span>      
                </div>
            </div>
               
            <div class = "form-group row ">
               <label for = "priority" class = "col-sm-2 col-form-label mr-0">Priority</label>
               <div class = "col-sm-4">
                  <input th:field="*{priority}" type = "text" class = "form-control" placeholder = "Low|Medium|High">
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <span class="error-message" th:errors="*{priority}"></span>      
                </div>
            </div>
               
            <div class = "form-group row">
                <label for = "comments" class = "col-sm-2 col-form-label">Comments</label>
                <div class = "col-sm-4">
                    <textarea th:field="*{comment}" class = "form-control" rows = "3" placeholder = "Max. 50 chars"></textarea>
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <span class="text-danger" th:errors="*{comment}"> </span>      
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class = "form-group row">
               <div class = "col-sm-10">
                  <input th:field="*{id}" type="hidden"></input>
                  <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
               </div>            
            </div>
            
         </form>
```

.
@Valid annotation never detect errors

However the validation doesn't seem to work and is not throwing any validation error. at line 27 of the controller bindingResult.hasErrors() is always false. What am I missing? Any help is appreciated!

[github repository](https://github.com/fouapon/watchlist)

Comment: Hey, you should read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Don't post images of code. Post the actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with spring boot 2.3, you need to add spring-boot-starter-validation to use @Valid.

Add this dependency to your pom.xml

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId> 
</dependency>
```

Also add @RequestBody at your post api.

```
public ModelAndView submitWatchlistItemForm(@Valid @RequestBody WatchlistItem watchlistItem, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: thankyou @Shawrup.  I added the dependency to the pom.xml and it's work.